# ASP EF Model Design Strategy

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

"Movie" table

```
public int movieId { get; set; }
public String movieName { get; set; }
public virtual Genres Genres { get; set; }
```

"Genre" table

```
public int genreId { get; set; }
public String genreName { get; set; }
```

What I am looking for is a strategy to building the model to accomplish the following scenario:

1. An admin person enters all the genre names, no more to be added afterwards
2. A non-admin enters a movie and on that same screen is offered a dropdownlist with all "admin-typed" genres names

My problem is that when they create a movie, linq also wants to create a new genre record

I don't want any more genres records created, I only want the table looked at for the genre list

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would change the property names and class name to make it a bit more readable. If you keep the primary key column name of your `Genre` table as `GenreId`, EF Codefirst is going to create the foreign key (in movie) table with name `Genre_GenreId` !!. So i changed the primary key column name of Movie class to simply `ID`, so that it will generate the foreign key column as `Genre_ID`

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String MovieName { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genres { get; set; }
}
public class Genre
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your UI, you give a dropdown where it lists the Avaialble `Genre` records. When user submits the form, Save it like this

```
using (YourDBContext dbContext = new YourDBContext())
{
    Movie movie= new Movie { MovieName = "Read it from UI Please" };
    var genr=dbContext.Find(2); 
    // TO DO : replace 2 by selected value from dropdown in the UI
    movie.Genres =genr;

    dbContext.Movies.Add(movie);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();     
}
```

You are loading the Genre object from your db context first and set that as the `Genres` property of the new movie object. We are using the `Find` method to findout the item whos primary key is the value passed to that function (in this case 2). This will add a new record to movie table and Set the `GenreID` column value as `2`, assuming you have a record with ID `2` in your Genre table

Comment: to clarify: "movie.Genres = new Genre { ID = 2 };" is creating a new object to send to Genre Genre, because Genre is an object of another table?

Comment: I am not able to get it to add the movie unless I put:  movie.Genres = new Genre { ID = 2, Name = "whatever" }; which then makes a new Genre record

Comment: I tried only setting the ID, the database wouldn't take it on SaveChanges.....I added the name to see what it wanted and that was it.

Comment: @user2182715: Oh ! you need to load the Object from dbcontext and set that as the property. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to create a new `Genre` when you create a new `Movie`, you might be doing something wrong when inserting the `Movie`. Here's a tip on how to do it using EF and MVC:

```
// Model with foreign key
public class Movie {
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
}

public class Genre {
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Movie Controller setting the genres for the view
public ViewResult Create() {
    // ...
    var genres = repository.Genres.All();
    ViewBag.GenreId = genres;
}

// View
@Html.DropDown("GenreId")


// Movie controller, GenreId on the model will be 
// automatically populated via model binding and the
// correct genre will be inserted
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.Movies.Add(movie);
        repository.SaveChanges();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: you added "public int GenreId { get; set; }"....what effect does this have on the "Genre Genre" Movie property? Isn't Genre still a required property?

Comment: The effect is that when `GenreId` is populated in the view (using the dropdown), then the model binding populates the `movie.GenreId` property and you can insert that value using EF **without** associating a `Genre` object to the `movie` object, only GenreId.

EF understands `GenreId` on the `Movie` model as a `ForeignKeyAttribute` set on the `Genre` poiting to `GenreId`.